# json login on spring security

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-security

I'm building a REST back end based on spring and i'm using spring security to secure the requests. But i'm lookin for an issue to login by sending parameters in json rather than defaults parameters sent by the default login page of spring security.

I'm working with spring security 4.0.1 and spring 4.1

Any issue please?

Comment: What are the parameters? Still just username and password or something else?

Comment: Yes just those, and may be also the authorizations

Answer (score 0):

If you're using just username and password, you can simply add a new filter to the stack, akin to the existing `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, that would react to a specific URL only (just like the default one reacts to `j_spring_security_check` only), parse the JSON and create the very same `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` that the default filter creates. This leaves the auth provider the same as the token didn't change.

If you need more fields in addition to username and password, either create a new token type (or use existing one if it makes sense) and a new auth provider that can deal with that token type. You can also just cram extra fields into `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` using `setDetails()`, but this is a bit hacky.